# How do I host CoreNLP server with caseless models?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to host a CoreNLP server but with the caseless models but I don't think I was successful and the official site doesn't have example hosting such model.

I'm currently hosting with:

```
java -mx4g \
           -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
           -port 9000 \
           -timeout 15000
```

but this is the default way of hosting which doesn't use the caseless models. I checked the app log and it was loading the standard models instead of caseless models:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.9 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.5 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.5 sec].
```

According to https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/caseless.html, I have downloaded the english models jar file and put it under the corenlp module folder, but I don't know exactly how to specify and use those for server hosting.

In the client side, I'm doing the following:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://[::]:9000/?properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,truecase,pos,ner","outputFormat":"json"}', 
                  data="show me hotels in toronto for next weekend")
print(r.text)
```

The truecase is working, but I don't see the caseless models being used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the property `"ner.model": "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz"`

Also you may want to use Stanza for accessing the Stanford CoreNLP server.

Details here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html#overview

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution earlier as well that I had to specify the ner model. I didn't know that stanza has an client interface for CoreNLP, I will look into it but since the server is for multiple usages so I guess it makes more sense to host it somewhere instead of spinning up a server everytime.

Comment: You can access an externally running server with stanza.